# How do i run a perl script (possible missing dependencies)

Tags: 16.04, scripts, dependencies, gtk, perl

I'm trying to use this little script because my cat loves walking on my keyboard.
http://linux.softpedia.com/get/Utilities/Lock-keyboard-for-Baby-23745.shtml

I just installed Ubuntu16.04 and don't have a lot of experience.
So i figured i would use the terminal to navigate to the folder i downloaded the script into and then do

```
perl scriptname.pl
```

Which outputs this:

```
Can't locate Gtk2.pm in @INC (you may need to install the Gtk2 module) (@INC contains: /etc/perl /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.22.1 /usr/local/share/perl/5.22.1 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl5/5.22 /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.22 /usr/share/perl/5.22 /usr/local/lib/site_perl /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl-base .) at keylock.pl line 128.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at keylock.pl line 128.
```

It seems like a missing dependency but i can't figure out what to install.

```
sudo apt-get install gtk2.0  
sudo apt-get install build-essential libgtk2.0-dev  
sudo apt-get update
```

will only tell me they are installed and up to date.
What can i do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need Perl interface to Gtk2, it should exist as [libgtk2-perl](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libgtk2-perl).

Comment: Yep that worked. Thank you!  /solved